# Tetrahedralize Mesh

Tags: surfaces, solid-geometry

Say I have a triangle mesh which forms the shell of an object which may not be convex. For every triangle, I have the vertices and a normal. I want to turn this mesh into a solid. I want to break up the geometry into a bunch of non-intersecting tetrahedra that fully fill the space. What algorithm could I use to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Look up "Tetrahedral mesh generation". There are many approaches, and many applications.